# Plot with d3.js in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, d3.js

Since Google Apps Script is in javascript, I was wondering if I could somehow import it and use it instead of the charting library.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2016, it works perfectly. Here is a simple example.

[D3 within GAS](http://bit.ly/1QmhNbG)

You can find the code here: [github-D3-GAS](http://bit.ly/1KAoWs8)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in principle you can include any Javascript library you like. However, it must comply with Google's Caja sanitization - [see the "JavaScript Libraries" subheading here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#Caja). You will need to build your app using the [Html Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) and not [Ui Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp).

---

[Update 02/09/2015] The HtmlService has moved on a little since this was originally written. [This page on restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions) details more about the 3 different sandbox modes. The IFRAME mode does not use the Caja sanitization.

Comment: OK, thanks. So, should I just copy the code into a new file, d3.gs, and fix errors as they come up? I'd like this to run in a spreadsheet and send html emails.

Comment: I just tried including it as is with `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>` but that failed (with some useful errors), so your suggested approach sounds like a good place to start.

Comment: This [Google blog post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/using-open-source-libraries-in-apps.html) might help you, as that developer went through a similar process for the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library.

Comment: in my memory, caja does not support svg. it means d3.js can't use in htmlService. and caja has some canvas bugs...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import d3 and use it in Google Apps Script. To do so, you need to include it in your script as described here: https://github.com/d3/d3

Here is a hello world  [GAS script](https://gist.github.com/tanyagupta/bfb2e1da7186164b75cd66ef5d86c2c3) in Gist