# Animated charts using UiApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Script.

Is there a way to animate charts in a webapp using the Google Apps Script UiApp?

I tried returning the UiApp object twice in the doGet() function -- to change the values, but apparently it dosen't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an example of how to use animate using D3 within GAS. You can read about it in the answer here: [GAS-D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942431/plot-with-d3-js-in-google-apps-script)